# "E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75" when trying to run E2E in VSCode for an angular app

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, protractor, webdriver

I am trying to run the e2e for an Angular application in VSCode (command: ng e2e) and I get the below error.

My environment:

- Win 10
- VS Code version: 1.37.1
- Chrome version: Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

How could I update the chromedriver to match Chrome version?

```
Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.8) is greater than your local
version (7.3.5). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 22% building 103/109 modules 6 active ...e\workflow-manager-table.component.scssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

Date: 2019-09-03T18:20:59.131Z
Hash: 3ced9271ad10fcdd845e
Time: 14922ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 4.17 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.11 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.93 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tree.es5.js 38:63-88
"export 'CDK_TREE_NODE_OUTLET_NODE' was not found in '@angular/cdk/tree'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tree.es5.js 168:35-60
"export 'CDK_TREE_NODE_OUTLET_NODE' was not found in '@angular/cdk/tree'
[11:20:59] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
[11:20:59] I/config_source - curl -oC:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
[11:20:59] I/downloader - curl -oC:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/chromedriver_2.46.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/chromedriver_win32.zip
[11:20:59] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.46.zip
[11:21:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:21:00] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59746/devtools/browser/8a7f04ec-5be2-40bb-b68f-463b377c9c2b
[11:21:01] E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[11:21:01] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\_VSTS\OkhamaMD\OkhamaMDWebDemo\UI\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[11:21:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's because you have `Chrome version: Version 76.0.3809.132` as you pointed out.
This problem should be easily resolved by updating webdriver-manager & protractor:

`npm install -g webdriver-manager protractor && webdriver-manager update`

If that didn't work, try uninstalling it first, then re-install the latest version:

`npm uninstall -g webdriver-manager protractor`

then

`npm install -g webdriver-manager protractor` and `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't fix my problem, I still get the same error. This is what I did so far: 1. Deleted everything under node_modules; 2. ran "npm install"; 3. ran the command you suggested; 4. restarted VS Code.

Folder "node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium" still has chromedriver_2.46.exe and chromedriver_2.46.zip

Comment: I uninstalled it as you suggested and I installed it back. The latest version (76.0.3809.12) gets installed at "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium". However when I run the test from VS Code / Terminal using "ng e" the wrong version (2.46) gets copied at "node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium"

Comment: Hmm, I just created a new Angular app on the same machine and the e2e run just fine. It is something about this app, it has to have hardcoded somewhere the 2.46 version and i cannot find where that is.

Comment: I fixed this issue by uninstalling and installing protractor and webdriver-manager locally, not only globally, using the above commands without "-g"

Comment: It worked for me with slight variation:
`npm uninstall webdriver-manager protractor`
`npm install --save-dev webdriver-manager protractor && webdriver-manager update`

Removed -g (global)
Added --save-dev