# In Protractor, Error “session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84”

Tags: protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this problem for a few day and I have noticed that chromedriver version has been upgraded automaticlly to the 86. So I am guessing I need to downgrade it to 84. But I am not sure. May be I should upgrade something but I do not know what. My webdriver-manager vesrion is  `"webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",`
Any hints, please?

Comment: see if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777063/e-launcher-session-not-created-chrome-version-must-be-between-71-and-75-whe/57777445#57777445

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortuinatelly it doesn't fix the problem. I think I need to downgrade my ChromeDriver to 84 instead 86 but I don't know how. I just removed chromdriver version 86 and pasted 84 but still have same problem.

Comment: Finally I have disabled Chrome and enabled Firefox and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to resolve the webdriver update issue

`node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=<desired chrome version> --standalone --gecko=false --ignore_ssl`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to run on chrome browser.

In protractor sometime gets Error: ”Session not created ” because of not supported/incompatibility driver version for current browser version.

I have tried below steps:

Step 1: Delete selenium folder inside webdriver-manager .
All browser driver should be presented in this folder.
**Path:** ..\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

Step 2: `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` - This will download all browser driver versions inside selenium folder.

Or else you can update webdriver-manager with specific version you want.

`node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=XX.X.XXXX.X`